# MATLAB: Conversion to logical from sym is not possible

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

I'm having a problem with a user defined function I am constructing here. What I'm trying to do is to substitute a value into a symbolic function and then use that numerical answer for various purposes. Specifically here:

```
x = xo;
subst = subs(f,x);
while((n>i) && (subst > eps))
```

Running my program, I get the following error:

```
>> sym_newtonRaphson(f,fdiff,1,1e-8,10)
Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.

Error in sym_newtonRaphson (line 8)
```

I've tried using `double(subs(f,x))` to no avail. I seem to be getting a totally different error relating to MuPAD (`DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.`)

The following is the whole program:

```
function [output] = sym_newtonRaphson(f,fdiff,xo,eps,n)

i = 0;
%initial iteration
x = xo;
subst = subs(f,x);

  while((n>i) && (subst > eps))
     x = x - (subs(f,x))/fdiff;
     i = i+1;
     subst = subs(f,x);
     %fprintf('%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f',i,alpha,f(
  end
  output = x;
end
```

I'd appreciate some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong; all the best.

Comment: FYI. It looks like you're passing [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) in as an argument to your function. `eps`, [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), is a builtin constant (and function) available anywhere in Matlab. You don't need to pass it in and it's usually a good idea to avoid variable names that match common builtin function names (I don't care what people say [about `i` and `j`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740) though). If you like, create an argument called `tol` for your function and set it equal to `eps` or `1e-8`.

Comment: I use epsilon here as a tolerance value that I must input, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: try using `eval` instead of `subs`

Comment: If we knew what `f` and `xo` looked like, we could have a better idea of what was going on.

Comment: That would be: `f=8-4.5*(x-sin(x))` and `xo` is simply 1 as I showed here.

Comment: Tried using `eval` and it works wonderfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do with the `while` expression is equivalent to `logical(f)`, where `f` is a symbolic function (rather than a symbolic value). `logical(sym('exp(1)') > 0)` is fine, but `logical(sym('exp(f)') > 0)` is generally not going to be (see [`assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html)). Matlab has no way of casting a symbolic variable to a logical (true and false) one. It tries to do this because the [short circuit `AND` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html), `&&`, isn't supported for symbolic variables. For example

```
a = 1.5;
syms x;

% All of these will not generate errors
y1 = x > 1;
y2 = x > 1 & x < 2;
y3 = x > 1 & x < 2;
y4 = x > 1 & a < 2;
y5 = x > 1 & a > 2;

% These will result in errors
y2 = x > 1 && x < 2;
y3 = x > 1 && x < 2;
y4 = x > 1 && a < 2;
y5 = x > 1 && a > 2;
```

You should print out `subst` and make sure that it is a symbolic value or a function that does not include any variables (if `argnames(subst)` returns an empty symbolic matrix then you should be okay). The fact that you get the second error when you call `double` seems to imply that `subst` is actually an expression that still includes unknown variables. If this is the case, then you'll either need to substitute in other variables or use assumptions ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-for-symbolic-objects.html)) in order to do logical comparisons as you're doing.